# React error on Change this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to fix the following error:

`onChange={this.handleName}`

I am aware that I should make the binding inside the constructor and also I cannot make the binding inside the onChange, any ideas?

```js
class Register extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      surname: '',
      email: '',
    }
  }
  handleName(e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Dialog className={classes.root} open={isOpen}>
      <TextField label="NAME" onChange={this.handleName} fullWidth />
      </Dialog>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is arguably the most duplicated question for [tag:reactjs] on SO. With 28k rep you should know by now how to first check for existing questions before posting new ones.

Comment: @Chris sorry guys but today I was coding with fever :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function `handleName` is not bound to the class, currently the scope of `this` inside `handleName` is the function itself and not the class. So there is no `setState` function in that scope.

To correct this error, you can either put the binding of the function in your constructor.

```
constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      surname: '',
      email: '',
    }

    this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this,e);
  }
```

Or you can use arrow syntax to define the function

```
handleName = (e)=> {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `handleName` to `this`.

Instead of:

`onChange={this.handleName}`

Write it like:

`onChange={this.handleName.bind(this)}`.

This is because you're passing a function reference to `onChange` so when it executes it will be outside of your current scope, because of that `setState` won't exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Please add bind line in your constructor function.**

constructor(props: Props) {
....
 this.handleName = this.handleName .bind(this);
}

Answer (score 0):

Make `handleName` in form of the arrow function, whereby `this` will be referred to the component instance.

`handleName = (e) => {
  this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
}`

Answer (score 0):

You should `bind` your `handleName` function in the constructor method.

```
constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      surname: '',
      email: '',
    }
    this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: yes I know, but for various reasons I cannot do it